# traitCollectionDidChange: Called even I dont have any changes

Tags: ios

Do you know why `traitCollectionDidChange` is called even with no Size Class changes.

Selecting a UILabel, I have in my storyboard Attribute Inspector / Installed check for the UILabel. No special cases for installing according to Size Class.

Therefore I dont understand why `traitCollectionDidChange` is called when I rotate the device?

Yes, it is called after viewDidLod, but also every time I rotate the device/ emulator.

If I wanted to react to rotation I would use `viewWillTransitionToSize`.

Update: Hmm, re-thinking this. I guess that Size Class is actually also changing when you rotate an iPhone.

Can you think of traitCollectionDidChange as a specialised method of viewWillTransitionToSize - facilitating thresholds for telling when we are crossing Size Class boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size class will change if you rotate an iPhone, but won't change if you rotate an iPad (which has a regular size class for both horizontally and vertically).

Rotation is considered to be a change in the interface environment, therefore `traitCollectionDidChange` is called.

Comment: What if it happens even when I don't rotate or do anything? I'm having this problem right now in a keyboard extension: this method gets called twice: once before viewDidLoad, setting the initial size classes to hR wC, then almost immediately, setting the classes to hC wC.... I'm using iPhone 6 sim iOS 8.1 (it doesn't happen on 9.3/10.3 sims).

Comment: I don't know. Please post a new question.